# EE 2.6.1 Password not getting reset

Tags: password

I am trying to get the default Password Reset form working. I receive the email in my inbox, as expected, then I am taking to form asking for a new password and to confirm it. I click Submit and I am sorta taking to my index page. I say sorta because I have to refresh the page to actually see the page. Is this possibly why the password is not resetting?

I have tried this in Safari, Chrome and Firefox on the Mac.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you check if its related to this bug report https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19414

Comment: Did the trick! Thanks for the quick reply!